# Ansible execution environment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

When running a playbook using my custom execution environment I get the following error even though lxml is installed:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
```

How can I ensure lxml is available?

My files and process for building the execution environemnt...

`execution-environment.yaml`:

```
---
version: 1

build_arg_defaults:
  EE_BASE_IMAGE: 'quay.io/ansible/ansible-runner:stable-2.11-devel'

dependencies:
  galaxy: requirements.yml
  python: requirements.txt

additional_build_steps:
 prepend:
   - RUN pip install pip --upgrade
   - RUN whoami
   - RUN cat /etc/os-release
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
jmespath==0.9.4
netaddr==0.7.19
pyvcloud==21.0.1
```

> pyvcloud includes dependency for lxml

`requirements.yml`:

```
---
collections:
  - name: ansible.utils
    version: 2.3.1
  - name: community.general
  - name: ansible.netcommon
```

Building the image log:

```
ansible-builder build --tag=ee-vdc-provisioning -v3
Ansible Builder is building your execution environment image, "ee-vdc-provisioning".
File context/_build/requirements.yml is already up-to-date.
File context/_build/requirements.txt had modifications and will be rewritten
Rewriting Containerfile to capture collection requirements
Running command:
  docker build -f context/Dockerfile -t ee-vdc-provisioning context
Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB
Step 1/22 : ARG EE_BASE_IMAGE=quay.io/ansible/ansible-runner:stable-2.11-devel
Step 2/22 : ARG EE_BUILDER_IMAGE=quay.io/ansible/ansible-builder:latest
Step 3/22 : FROM $EE_BASE_IMAGE as galaxy
stable-2.11-devel: Pulling from ansible/ansible-runner
7a0437f04f83: Already exists
...
dea385bd2208: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:b5db8f78c5db830bd79589d926670cc6997a56e66ee1f4cf83f2d9600569489c
Status: Downloaded newer image for quay.io/ansible/ansible-runner:stable-2.11-devel
 ---> bac3a63558ef
Step 4/22 : ARG ANSIBLE_GALAXY_CLI_COLLECTION_OPTS=
 ---> Running in 4addc682993c
Removing intermediate container 4addc682993c
 ---> 76904e6db013
Step 5/22 : USER root
 ---> Running in c79b075ce2c1
Removing intermediate container c79b075ce2c1
 ---> b1e145b630fc
Step 6/22 : ADD _build /build
 ---> 0da78f554e57
Step 7/22 : WORKDIR /build
 ---> Running in d2d9e54e1deb
Removing intermediate container d2d9e54e1deb
 ---> b3eca50b6059
Step 8/22 : RUN ansible-galaxy role install -r requirements.yml --roles-path /usr/share/ansible/roles
 ---> Running in 65cb2c2993f6
Skipping install, no requirements found
Removing intermediate container 65cb2c2993f6
 ---> 7f9d44a54e1a
Step 9/22 : RUN ansible-galaxy collection install $ANSIBLE_GALAXY_CLI_COLLECTION_OPTS -r requirements.yml --collections-path /usr/share/ansible/collections
 ---> Running in f3f2ae1f8933
Starting galaxy collection install process
Process install dependency map
Starting collection install process
Downloading https://galaxy.ansible.com/download/ansible-utils-2.3.1.tar.gz to /home/runner/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1v97miv3n/tmpsqqgh1je/ansible-utils-2.3.1-7fqkmpu9
Installing 'ansible.utils:2.3.1' to '/usr/share/ansible/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/utils'
ansible.utils:2.3.1 was installed successfully
Downloading https://galaxy.ansible.com/download/ansible-netcommon-2.4.0.tar.gz to /home/runner/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1v97miv3n/tmpsqqgh1je/ansible-netcommon-2.4.0-lp5tkb63
Installing 'ansible.netcommon:2.4.0' to '/usr/share/ansible/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/netcommon'
ansible.netcommon:2.4.0 was installed successfully
Downloading https://galaxy.ansible.com/download/community-general-3.6.0.tar.gz to /home/runner/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1v97miv3n/tmpsqqgh1je/community-general-3.6.0-t9_6t8qg
Installing 'community.general:3.6.0' to '/usr/share/ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/general'
community.general:3.6.0 was installed successfully
Removing intermediate container f3f2ae1f8933
 ---> b8af138c706f
Step 10/22 : FROM $EE_BUILDER_IMAGE as builder
 ---> b8aaf3766431
Step 11/22 : COPY --from=galaxy /usr/share/ansible /usr/share/ansible
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d0ae7f063c09
Step 12/22 : ADD _build/requirements.txt requirements.txt
 ---> b93f1b4efd85
Step 13/22 : RUN ansible-builder introspect --sanitize --user-pip=requirements.txt --write-bindep=/tmp/src/bindep.txt --write-pip=/tmp/src/requirements.txt
 ---> Running in ce1856981322
# Sanitized dependencies for /usr/share/ansible/collections
---
python:
- 'ansible-pylibssh>=0.2.0  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'jxmlease  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'ncclient  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'netaddr==0.7.19  # from collection ansible.netcommon,user'
- 'paramiko  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'xmltodict  # from collection ansible.netcommon,ansible.utils'
- 'jsonschema  # from collection ansible.utils'
- 'textfsm  # from collection ansible.utils'
- 'ttp  # from collection ansible.utils'
- 'jmespath==0.9.4  # from collection user'
- 'pyvcloud==21.0.1  # from collection user'
system:
- 'gcc-c++ [doc test platform:rpm]  # from collection ansible.netcommon, ansible.utils'
- 'libyaml-devel [test platform:rpm]  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'libyaml-dev [test platform:dpkg]  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'python3-devel [test platform:rpm]  # from collection ansible.netcommon, ansible.utils'
- 'python3 [test platform:rpm]  # from collection ansible.netcommon, ansible.utils'
- 'gcc [compile platform:centos-8 platform:rhel-8]  # from collection ansible.netcommon,
  ansible.netcommon'
- 'libssh-devel [compile platform:centos-8 platform:rhel-8]  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'python38-Cython [compile platform:centos-8 platform:rhel-8]  # from collection
  ansible.netcommon'
- 'python38-six [platform:centos-8 platform:rhel-8]  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'python38-lxml [platform:centos-8 platform:rhel-8]  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'findutils [compile platform:centos-8 platform:rhel-8]  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'make [compile platform:centos-8 platform:rhel-8]  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'python38-devel [compile platform:centos-8 platform:rhel-8]  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'python38-cffi [platform:centos-8 platform:rhel-8]  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'python38-cryptography [platform:centos-8 platform:rhel-8]  # from collection ansible.netcommon'
- 'python38-pycparser [platform:centos-8 platform:rhel-8]  # from collection ansible.netcommon'

Creating parent directory for /tmp/src/requirements.txt
Removing intermediate container ce1856981322
 ---> 4c6b34447822
Step 14/22 : RUN assemble
 ---> Running in f55f696895c9
++ source /etc/os-release
+++ NAME='CentOS Linux'
+++ VERSION=8
+++ ID=centos
+++ ID_LIKE='rhel fedora'
+++ VERSION_ID=8
+++ PLATFORM_ID=platform:el8
+++ PRETTY_NAME='CentOS Linux 8'
+++ ANSI_COLOR='0;31'
+++ CPE_NAME=cpe:/o:centos:centos:8
+++ HOME_URL=https://centos.org/
+++ BUG_REPORT_URL=https://bugs.centos.org/
+++ CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT=CentOS-8
+++ CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION=8
++ echo centos
+ RELEASE=centos
+ PKGMGR=
+ PKGMGR_OPTS=
+ '[' -z ']'
+ PKGMGR=/usr/bin/dnf
+ '[' -f /usr/bin/microdnf ']'
+ mkdir -p /output/bindep
+ mkdir -p /output/wheels
+ mkdir -p /tmp/src
+ cd /tmp/src
+ /usr/bin/dnf update -y
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                      3.3 MB/s | 8.8 MB     00:02    
CentOS Linux 8 - BaseOS                          10 MB/s | 5.6 MB     00:00    
CentOS Linux 8 - Extras                         4.6 kB/s |  10 kB     00:02    
CentOS Linux 8 - PowerTools                     2.2 MB/s | 2.3 MB     00:01    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - 561 kB/s | 939 kB     00:01    
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
+ PACKAGES=
+ PIP_OPTS=
+ install_bindep
+ '[' -f bindep.txt ']'
+ bindep -l newline
+ sort
+ '[' centos == centos ']'
+ bindep -l newline -b epel
+ sort
+ grep -Fxvf /output/bindep/run.txt /output/bindep/stage.txt
+ true
+ rm -rf /output/bindep/stage.txt
++ bindep -b compile
++ true
+ compile_packages='gcc
libssh-devel
make
python38-Cython
python38-cffi
python38-cryptography
python38-devel
python38-lxml
python38-pycparser
python38-six'
+ '[' '!' -z 'gcc
libssh-devel
make
python38-Cython
python38-cffi
python38-cryptography
python38-devel
python38-lxml
python38-pycparser
python38-six' ']'
+ /usr/bin/dnf install -y gcc libssh-devel make python38-Cython python38-cffi python38-cryptography python38-devel python38-lxml python38-pycparser python38-six
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:10 ago on Wed Sep  8 06:32:08 2021.
Dependencies resolved.

Downloading Packages:
...  
(15/29): python38-lxml-4.4.1-5.module_el8.4.0+6 4.0 MB/s | 1.5 MB     00:00    
... 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           6.1 MB/s |  51 MB     00:08     
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                        1/1 
  Installing       : libmpc-1.1.0-9.1.el8.x86_64                           1/29 
  Installing       : cpp-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64                                2/29 
  ...
  Verifying        : python38-lxml-4.4.1-5.module_el8.4.0+647+0ba99ce8.   13/29 
  ...

Installed:
  cmake-filesystem-3.18.2-11.el8_4.x86_64                                       
  cpp-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64                                                        
  gcc-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64                                                        
  ....                       
  python38-lxml-4.4.1-5.module_el8.4.0+647+0ba99ce8.x86_64                      
  ...                   

Complete!
+ python3 -m venv /tmp/venv --system-site-packages --without-pip
+ source /tmp/venv/bin/activate
++ deactivate nondestructive
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ '[' -n /bin/bash -o -n '' ']'
++ hash -r
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ unset VIRTUAL_ENV
++ '[' '!' nondestructive = nondestructive ']'
++ VIRTUAL_ENV=/tmp/venv
++ export VIRTUAL_ENV
++ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
++ PATH=/tmp/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
++ export PATH
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1=
++ '[' 'x(venv) ' '!=' x ']'
++ PS1='(venv) '
++ export PS1
++ '[' -n /bin/bash -o -n '' ']'
++ hash -r
+ '[' -f /tmp/src/upper-constraints.txt ']'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ install_wheels
+ '[' -f /tmp/src/build-requirements.txt ']'
+ '[' -f setup.py ']'
+ '[' -f /tmp/src/requirements.txt ']'
+ '[' '!' -f /output/requirements.txt ']'
+ pip3 install --cache-dir=/output/wheels -r /tmp/src/requirements.txt
Collecting ansible-pylibssh>=0.2.0
  Downloading ansible_pylibssh-0.2.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
Collecting jxmlease
  Downloading jxmlease-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting ncclient
  Downloading ncclient-0.6.12.tar.gz (106 kB)
Collecting netaddr==0.7.19
  Downloading netaddr-0.7.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting paramiko
  Downloading paramiko-2.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (206 kB)
Collecting xmltodict
  Downloading xmltodict-0.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)
Collecting jsonschema
  Downloading jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Collecting textfsm
  Downloading textfsm-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
Collecting ttp
  Downloading ttp-0.7.2.tar.gz (63 kB)
Collecting jmespath==0.9.4
  Downloading jmespath-0.9.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting pyvcloud==21.0.1
  Downloading pyvcloud-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (204 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=4.2.1 in /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from pyvcloud==21.0.1->-r /tmp/src/requirements.txt (line 11)) (4.4.1)
Collecting humanfriendly>=4.8
  Downloading humanfriendly-9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (86 kB)
Collecting unittest-xml-reporting>=2.2.1
  Downloading unittest_xml_reporting-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.18.4
  Downloading requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=4.2b1 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from pyvcloud==21.0.1->-r /tmp/src/requirements.txt (line 11)) (5.4.1)
Collecting pygments>=2.2.0
  Downloading Pygments-2.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>0.6 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ncclient->-r /tmp/src/requirements.txt (line 3)) (41.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ncclient->-r /tmp/src/requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.12.0)
Collecting bcrypt>=3.1.3
  Downloading bcrypt-3.2.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (63 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.5 in /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from paramiko->-r /tmp/src/requirements.txt (line 5)) (2.8)
Collecting pynacl>=1.0.1
  Downloading PyNaCl-1.4.0-cp35-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (961 kB)
Collecting pyrsistent>=0.14.0
  Downloading pyrsistent-0.18.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (118 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.4.0
  Downloading attrs-21.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting future
  Downloading future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.1 in /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko->-r /tmp/src/requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko->-r /tmp/src/requirements.txt (line 5)) (2.19)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Downloading certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0
  Downloading charset_normalizer-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.18.4->pyvcloud==21.0.1->-r /tmp/src/requirements.txt (line 11)) (2.8)
Building wheels for collected packages: ncclient, ttp, future
  Building wheel for ncclient (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for ncclient (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for ncclient: filename=ncclient-0.6.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=83781 sha256=ab7ff67d84af8ee205b2127d84facfe7c3004ac2baf7f9044992d8611c1f9aba
  Stored in directory: /output/wheels/wheels/b2/ea/95/9bdf798bf88d883a5ee9536d8a483042030d182ab252953b9d
  Building wheel for ttp (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for ttp (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for ttp: filename=ttp-0.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=82592 sha256=4128235c837b71ad65b52aeab39073636cba7aabdfe6e67aa0bf1822d56758d6
  Stored in directory: /output/wheels/wheels/a5/e9/86/589e41ee5c74286a197095d4aabff1896eea950bb45ea593be
  Building wheel for future (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for future (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for future: filename=future-0.18.2-py3-none-any.whl size=491056 sha256=9aa6ce7d6e6150df9cfa35c0debb6e450d447eaec1789a03e34d9bc47084859a
  Stored in directory: /output/wheels/wheels/8e/70/28/3d6ccd6e315f65f245da085482a2e1c7d14b90b30f239e2cf4
Successfully built ncclient ttp future
Installing collected packages: urllib3, pynacl, charset-normalizer, certifi, bcrypt, unittest-xml-reporting, requests, pyrsistent, pygments, paramiko, humanfriendly, future, attrs, xmltodict, ttp, textfsm, pyvcloud, netaddr, ncclient, jxmlease, jsonschema, jmespath, ansible-pylibssh
Successfully installed ansible-pylibssh-0.2.0 attrs-21.2.0 bcrypt-3.2.0 certifi-2021.5.30 charset-normalizer-2.0.4 future-0.18.2 humanfriendly-9.2 jmespath-0.9.4 jsonschema-3.2.0 jxmlease-1.0.3 ncclient-0.6.12 netaddr-0.7.19 paramiko-2.7.2 pygments-2.10.0 pynacl-1.4.0 pyrsistent-0.18.0 pyvcloud-21.0.1 requests-2.26.0 textfsm-1.1.2 ttp-0.7.2 unittest-xml-reporting-3.0.4 urllib3-1.26.6 xmltodict-0.12.0
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
+ cp /tmp/src/requirements.txt /output/requirements.txt
++ ls -1 '/output/wheels/*whl'
++ wc -l
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
++ get-extras-packages
+ /usr/bin/dnf clean all
38 files removed
+ rm -rf /var/cache/dnf /var/cache/yum
+ rm -rf /var/lib/dnf/history.sqlite /var/lib/dnf/history.sqlite-shm /var/lib/dnf/history.sqlite-wal
+ rm -rf /var/log/dnf.librepo.log /var/log/dnf.log /var/log/dnf.rpm.log /var/log/hawkey.log
+ rm -rf /tmp/venv
Removing intermediate container f55f696895c9
 ---> f52fd8437571
Step 15/22 : FROM $EE_BASE_IMAGE
 ---> bac3a63558ef
Step 16/22 : USER root
 ---> Running in fc6888e27374
Removing intermediate container fc6888e27374
 ---> ee14881aa582
Step 17/22 : RUN pip install pip --upgrade
 ---> Running in d7f03db5ab97
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (21.2.4)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Removing intermediate container d7f03db5ab97
 ---> 1b7904758bf0
Step 18/22 : RUN whoami
 ---> Running in 161168263f0f
root
Removing intermediate container 161168263f0f
 ---> 1e54d5ebed25
Step 19/22 : RUN cat /etc/os-release
 ---> Running in 8f2e3985f498
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="8"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="8"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 8"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:8"
HOME_URL="https://centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-8"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="8"
Removing intermediate container 8f2e3985f498
 ---> 7aa8d50dcc2b
Step 20/22 : COPY --from=galaxy /usr/share/ansible /usr/share/ansible
 ---> c1f18affa806
Step 21/22 : COPY --from=builder /output/ /output/
 ---> b237b7b29502
Step 22/22 : RUN /output/install-from-bindep && rm -rf /output/wheels
 ---> Running in 52b7c2a29525
+ PKGMGR=
+ PKGMGR_OPTS=
+ '[' -z ']'
+ PKGMGR=/usr/bin/dnf
+ '[' -f /usr/bin/microdnf ']'
+ /usr/bin/dnf update -y
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                      4.1 MB/s | 8.8 MB     00:02    
CentOS Linux 8 - BaseOS                         7.0 MB/s | 5.6 MB     00:00    
CentOS Linux 8 - Extras                          13 kB/s |  10 kB     00:00    
CentOS Linux 8 - PowerTools                     3.0 MB/s | 2.3 MB     00:00    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - 512 kB/s | 939 kB     00:01    
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Wed Sep  8 06:33:45 2021.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
+ '[' -f /output/bindep/run.txt ']'
++ cat /output/bindep/run.txt
+ PACKAGES='python38-cffi
python38-cryptography
python38-lxml
python38-pycparser
python38-six'
+ '[' '!' -z 'python38-cffi
python38-cryptography
python38-lxml
python38-pycparser
python38-six' ']'
+ /usr/bin/dnf install -y python38-cffi python38-cryptography python38-lxml python38-pycparser python38-six
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:04 ago on Wed Sep  8 06:33:45 2021.
Package python38-cffi-1.13.2-3.module_el8.4.0+647+0ba99ce8.x86_64 is already installed.
Package python38-cryptography-2.8-3.module_el8.4.0+647+0ba99ce8.x86_64 is already installed.
Package python38-lxml-4.4.1-5.module_el8.4.0+647+0ba99ce8.x86_64 is already installed.
Package python38-pycparser-2.19-3.module_el8.4.0+647+0ba99ce8.noarch is already installed.
Package python38-six-1.12.0-10.module_el8.4.0+647+0ba99ce8.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
+ '[' -f /output/bindep/epel.txt ']'
++ cat /output/bindep/epel.txt
+ EPEL_PACKAGES=
+ '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -f /output/upper-constraints.txt ']'
+ '[' -f /output/requirements.txt ']'
+ pip3 install --cache-dir=/output/wheels -r /output/requirements.txt
Collecting ansible-pylibssh>=0.2.0
  Using cached ansible_pylibssh-0.2.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
Collecting jxmlease
  Using cached jxmlease-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: ncclient in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r /output/requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.6.12)
Collecting netaddr==0.7.19
  Using cached netaddr-0.7.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: paramiko in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r /output/requirements.txt (line 5)) (2.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: xmltodict in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r /output/requirements.txt (line 6)) (0.12.0)
Collecting jsonschema
  Using cached jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Collecting textfsm
  Using cached textfsm-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
Collecting ttp
  Using cached ttp-0.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jmespath==0.9.4
  Using cached jmespath-0.9.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting pyvcloud==21.0.1
  Using cached pyvcloud-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (204 kB)
Collecting unittest-xml-reporting>=2.2.1
  Using cached unittest_xml_reporting-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting pygments>=2.2.0
  Using cached Pygments-2.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=4.2b1 in /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from pyvcloud==21.0.1->-r /output/requirements.txt (line 11)) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=4.2.1 in /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from pyvcloud==21.0.1->-r /output/requirements.txt (line 11)) (4.4.1)
Collecting humanfriendly>=4.8
  Using cached humanfriendly-9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (86 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.18.4 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyvcloud==21.0.1->-r /output/requirements.txt (line 11)) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ncclient->-r /output/requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>0.6 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ncclient->-r /output/requirements.txt (line 3)) (41.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from paramiko->-r /output/requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt>=3.1.3 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from paramiko->-r /output/requirements.txt (line 5)) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.5 in /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from paramiko->-r /output/requirements.txt (line 5)) (2.8)
Collecting pyrsistent>=0.14.0
  Using cached pyrsistent-0.18.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (118 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.4.0
  Using cached attrs-21.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting future
  Using cached future-0.18.2-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.1 in /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko->-r /output/requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko->-r /output/requirements.txt (line 5)) (2.19)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.18.4->pyvcloud==21.0.1->-r /output/requirements.txt (line 11)) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.18.4->pyvcloud==21.0.1->-r /output/requirements.txt (line 11)) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.18.4->pyvcloud==21.0.1->-r /output/requirements.txt (line 11)) (1.25.7)
Installing collected packages: unittest-xml-reporting, pyrsistent, pygments, humanfriendly, future, attrs, ttp, textfsm, pyvcloud, netaddr, jxmlease, jsonschema, jmespath, ansible-pylibssh
Successfully installed ansible-pylibssh-0.2.0 attrs-21.2.0 future-0.18.2 humanfriendly-9.2 jmespath-0.9.4 jsonschema-3.2.0 jxmlease-1.0.3 netaddr-0.7.19 pygments-2.10.0 pyrsistent-0.18.0 pyvcloud-21.0.1 textfsm-1.1.2 ttp-0.7.2 unittest-xml-reporting-3.0.4
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
+ EXTRAS=
+ '[' -f /output/packages.txt ']'
++ ls -1 '/output/wheels/*whl'
++ wc -l
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+ /usr/bin/dnf clean all
38 files removed
+ rm -rf /var/cache/dnf /var/cache/yum
+ rm -rf /var/lib/dnf/history.sqlite /var/lib/dnf/history.sqlite-shm /var/lib/dnf/history.sqlite-wal
+ rm -rf /var/log/dnf.librepo.log /var/log/dnf.log /var/log/dnf.rpm.log /var/log/hawkey.log
Removing intermediate container 52b7c2a29525
 ---> 546ab86ee4cb
Successfully built 546ab86ee4cb
Successfully tagged ee-vdc-provisioning:latest

Complete! The build context can be found at: /repo/awx/execution_environments/vdc_provisioning/context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure to add a `bindep.txt` file:

```
python38-devel [platform:rpm compile]
subversion [platform:rpm]
subversion [platform:dpkg]
git-lfs [platform:rpm]
```

and add it to your `execution-environment.yml`:

```
dependencies:
  galaxy: requirements.yml
  python: requirements.txt
  system: bindep.txt
```

Someone else must explain what the system level dependencies are but this is what the docs say and `lxml` won't work without it:

> The bindep requirements file specifies cross-platform requirements, if there are any.  These get processed by bindep and then passed to dnf (other platforms are not yet supported as of the publication of this blog post)